# Provide custom implementation for DNS lookup in java.net.URL class

Tags: java, caching, dns

I was wondering if it's possible to provide a custom implementation for DNS lookups on java.net.URL - my hosting provider's DNS gets flaky at certain times of day and then DNS lookups fail for a few minutes, but if I manually configure the relevant domains in my hosts file, they work fine, so what I want to do is have some sort of DNS cache at a software level, if DNS lookup succeed, update the cache, if it fails, fall back to the cached IP address and open the URLConnection on that IP address.

This is my URL connection implementation:

```
    URL endpoint = new URL(null, url, new URLStreamHandler() {
        @Override
        protected URLConnection openConnection(URL url)
                throws IOException {
            URL target = new URL(url.toString());
            URLConnection connection = target.openConnection();
            // Connection settings
            connection.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeout);
            connection.setReadTimeout(readTimeout);
            return (connection);
        }
    });
```

I was looking at proxies on [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html), but can't see any immediate way to do custom DNS lookups at the software level.

**Limitations**:

1: It needs to work in Java6 (maybe Java7, but the client won't be switching to Java8 anytime soon)

2: Can't add JVM args

3: I don't own these endpoints, so substituting the hostname with an IP address is not a solution since load balancers will serve different content / APIs depending on whether you come from a hostname or an IP address. As an example: mail.google.com resolves to 216.58.223.37, going to that IP address will serve google.com content and not mail.google.com content, since both services are sitting behind the same load balancer using a single IP address.

4: I don't know how many URLs' DNS resolutions I'll need to cache, but I do know it won't be more than a 1000. Ideal solution would be to have the DNS resolutions in a static hashmap, if any DNS resolution succeed, update the hashmap, if it fails, use the DNS resolution in the hashmap.

5: If there's a native java solution, I'd prefer that over using JNI - [Understanding host name resolution and DNS behavior in Java](http://www.myhowto.org/java/42-understanding-host-name-resolution-and-dns-behavior-in-java/)

Comment: For want of a more elegant solution, could you simply replace the host portion of the URL with the IP address that your custom DNS implementation would return? Using plain old String manipulation, I mean.

Comment: I have about 500 URLs that I would need to maintain, I was hoping for a solution where I can just have a static hashmap and do in memory lookups for the 90 seconds DNS is flaky maybe once a day.

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert did you solve the problem? my code can't access AWS running on hackerrank. any id how to get ip or change dns?

Comment: I've posted my solution. If it doesn't help, please post a new Stack Overflow question and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: won't work in my case i have no access to /etc/hosts, if you know any solution plz let me know

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom method to check whether the host resolves to an IP. Prior to opening the connection if the host does not resolve then do your lookup and use the IP directly to build the URL instead:

At class level:

```
private Map<String,InetAddress> cacheMap = new HashMap<String,InetAddress>();
```

....then a couple of methods to build your URL:

```
private URL buildUrl (String host) throws MalformedURLException {
    InetAddress ia = resolveHostToIp(host);
    URL url = null;

    if (ia != null) {
        url = new URL(ia.getHostAddress());
    } else {
        // Does not resolve and is not in cache....dunno
    }
    return url;
}


 private InetAddress resolveHostToIp(String host) {
    InetAddress ia = null;
    try {
        ia = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        // Update your cache
        cacheMap.put(host, ia);
    } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
        System.out.println("\"" + host + "\" does not resolve to an IP! Looking for it in the cacheMap....");
        // Head off to your cache and return the InetAddress from there.....
        ia = cacheMap.get(host);
    }
    return ia;
}
```

Comment: Some of these endpoints I connect to are sitting on AWS and GCE, if you resolve an IP address for www.example.com, you get an IP address, but POSTing to an IP address and POSTing to a HOST name will give completely different results if there are multiple services running on that IP address.

Comment: OK. Was not aware of that from your question. So how would "if it fails, fall back to the cached IP address and open the URLConnection on that IP address" work then if there are multiple services running on the IP?

Comment: Substituting the host with an IP address would have been a solution if were controlling the endpoints, unfortunately I'm not. Let's take mail.google.com as an arbitrary example, it resolves to 216.58.223.37, but accessing it goes to google.com instead of mail.google.com

Comment: NGINX / Apache / ... load balancers decide which service to load depending on your host name, if you come in via an IP address, you're effectively coming in via a different hostname.

Comment: OK. Understand that. Can I suggest that you amend your original question to include this extra information? ATM the question doesn't include any of these details!

Comment: Just did, might not be a simple problem to solve, I'm guessing DNS resolution happens at the OS layer.

Answer (score -1):

You could simply construct another URL:

```
URL target = new URL(
    url.getProtocol(),
    customDns.resolve(url.getHost()),
    url.getFile());
```

You can implement `customDns.resolve(String)` using whatever strategy you need.

Comment: Substituting the host with an IP address would have been a solution if were controlling the endpoints, unfortunately I'm not. Let's take mail.google.com as an arbitrary example, it resolves to 216.58.223.37, but accessing it goes to google.com instead of mail.google.com